# How to set up iptables to access my apache2 server from public IP

Tags: 20.04, apache2, iptables, firewall, ufw

I've got my Oracle Cloud instance on ubuntu 20.04 and I set up apache2 server. It's working from `curl localhost` but It doesn't work from my instance public IP. My ufw status:

```
Status: active

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
22/tcp                     ALLOW       Anywhere
Apache                     ALLOW       Anywhere
80/tcp                     ALLOW       Anywhere
OpenSSH                    ALLOW       Anywhere
OpenSSH (v6)               ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
22/tcp (v6)                ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
Apache (v6)                ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
80/tcp (v6)                ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
```

If I would do like `sudo ufw disable` It still doesn't connect.

It connects only if I do:

```
iptables -P INPUT ACCEPT
iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT
iptables -P FORWARD ACCEPT
iptables -F
```

But I obviously don't want to do that.

If I add some rules to iptables:

```
sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --sport 80 -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
sudo netfilter-persistent save
```

It doesn't change anything

***EDIT***

`sudo iptables -S OUTPUT`:

```
-P OUTPUT ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -d 169.254.0.0/16 -j InstanceServices
-A OUTPUT -j ufw-before-logging-output
-A OUTPUT -j ufw-before-output
-A OUTPUT -j ufw-after-output
-A OUTPUT -j ufw-after-logging-output
-A OUTPUT -j ufw-reject-output
-A OUTPUT -j ufw-track-output
-A OUTPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -p tcp -m tcp --sport 80 -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

Comment: Does the machine have a public IP address? What do you see when you type `ifconfig` (You may need to install `net-tools` for this function if you don't already have it).

Comment: As i wrote. If I do:
`iptables -P INPUT ACCEPT
iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT
iptables -P FORWARD ACCEPT
iptables -F`
I can connect just fine(with public IP)

Comment: And I didn't have `net-tools` so installed it but nothing has changed

Comment: ufw is just a front end for iptables. Show us the output for `sudo iptables -xnvL`, and maybe we can help, although ufw generated iptables rules are difficult to read and follow. And yes, disabling ufw doesn't flush its rule set.

Comment: I put `sudo iptables -S output` in the post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be mixing and matching between using raw iptables, and ufw (which is a front-end to iptables)

I think the first thing to do is delete all ufw rules, and flush iptables. then pick one (either raw iptables, or a front-end). then just use that. Mixing and matching between the two is going to cause all sorts of issues

Comment: If i do 
`sudo ufw disable` 
`sudo ufw reset`
`sudo iptables -F` 
`sudo ufw allow 22/tcp` 
 Everything is fine but if I: 
`sudo ufw enable` 
 I loose my ssh connection and then I have to reboot the instance and everything is restored

Comment: Sorry. There's weirdness here I don't understand. Hopefully someone understands.

Comment: Thank you anyway :)

Comment: I had to `sudo apt autormeove --purge ufw` and the same for iptables. Then i reinstalled it and now everything works fine

Comment: lol - weirdness solved. Glad it's ok now